# FFMpeg change video bitrate way faster

Tags: ffmpeg

im using this command to change the video bitrate it works good , but it delays a lot , 
like 45 minutes - 1 hour for each video, is there other some way that is faster? `ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -b 25500k -minrate 25500k -maxrate 25500k -bufsize 25500k outxd.mkv`

Comment: Is a GPU available?  You can offload the transcoding to it.  Also, what codec are you using?

Comment: Yes gpu is available how to do it? , the codec is MPEG-4 AVC

Comment: What GPU and platform?

Comment: GPU is GTX 1080 and windows 10 , cpu is i7 8700k

Comment: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/

Comment: So like this ? ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -hwaccel cuvid -b 25500k -minrate 25500k -maxrate 25500k -bufsize 25500k outxd.mkv

Comment: You need to read that guide in more detail.  Do what it suggests, and then try it and see what happens.

Comment: There is no guide for windows 10

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect anyone to help you.  In that guide are several examples for you to follow, and they do work on Windows 10.  If it isn't working for you, we could only guess why because you didn't show us the command you ran or what the result is.

Comment: Show the complete log from the command you showed in your question.